# Android Studio getText() and setText() not working with error: "can't resolve method "getText/setText"()"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So my app needs to read text from a text box with a tag of "inText" do stuff to it (that stuff works) then write the output to a box with the id of "outView". I've been doing this with setText() and getText().

setText() was for writing the output below is what I used:

```
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.outView.setText(textoutput));
```

getText() was for reading the input text then writing it to a variable and below is what I used:

```
String mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inText.getText()).toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `getText()` and `setText()` method in wrong place. 
`getText()` and `setText()` are methods of TextView and EditText classes.
But here you used it as a method of id. That's why it's showing "Can't resolve method getText/setText()". As id has no such methods.

You can do the following.

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.outView)).setText(textoutput);
```

and

```
String mEdit = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inText)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: @DannyPiper Can you not see my answer which is well over 20 minutes before this one?

Comment: @DannyPiper Welcome, :)

Answer (score 4):

You're chaining the method at the wrong spot. Remove `.getText()` from `R.id.inText` and place it after the brackets like (same thing for `TextView`):

```
String mEdit = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.inText)).getText().toString();
```

Though this is an uncommon way to do thing. Rather initialize the EditText first and then get the text, it's much clearer that way:

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inText);
String mText = mEdit.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working since you need to first set the TextView:

```
 TextView tvOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outView);
 TextView tvIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inText);

 String out = tvOut.getText().toString();
 String in = tvIn.setText(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a field check the compiler didn't automatically set it as a view instead of EditText type.

Also the casts are redundant now so you better not use them if you don't have to